# why: Input type (torch.cuda.FloatTensor) and weight type (torch.FloatTensor) should be the same

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I'm writing neural networks using torch. Here's a little problem I can't solve.
I've put both network and network inputs into the GPU, but there was an error in training.

```
RuntimeError: Input type (torch.cuda.FloatTensor) and weight type (torch.FloatTensor) should be the same
```

Comment: You need to show your code!

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem.

After reviewing the training function, I confirm that the model and input data have been loaded onto the GPU. Then the problem must be in the network model. When I checked the network model, I found that I wasn't using structures like List. It is likely that the model was not loaded into the GPU when other custom network models were used.

So I checked each layer of the network model, which is to force each layer onto the GPU (`.cuda()`). Depending on where the error prompt is located, the problem was identified after each layer's attempt, which was that the model was not loaded onto the GPU when a custom model was called.

Finally, simply find the location to call the custom model in the network-defined forward function and force it into the GPU(`.cuda()`).